# probabilityproblem

Tags: probability

A and B play a game of chess. They play 20 games of which A wins 12 and B wins 4.The remaining 4 games are drawn.If 3 games are played between them, find the probability that 
i)B wins at least 1 game?ii) the probability that 2 games are drawn?

Comment: Well... You can't find it without at least trying to look for it, can you?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

- If a game is played then what is the probability that $B$ will loose the game?
- If $3$ games are played then what is the probability that $B$ looses all games?
- If $3$ games are played then what is the probability that $B$ does not loose all games?

Answer (score 0):

20 games are not enough to establish the relative chess playing abilites of A and B but If we assume that they are representative; That is if they played 20 million games we get wins, losses and draws in the same proportion then B fails to win $\dfrac{16}{20} = \dfrac{4}{5}$ of the time.

The probability of B not winning any game is thus $\left(\dfrac{4}{5}\right)^3=\dfrac{64}{125}$ and the probability of winning at least one game is $1 - \dfrac{64}{125} = \dfrac{61}{125} = 0.488$